# How to deal with guid or uuid type primary key in Yii's urlManager instead of only digital type?

Tags: yii, primary-key, guid, uuid

I'm trying to figure out how to pass the guid type primary key value in the HTTP GET method  to the controller.
I have changed my urlManager as follows:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:^[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12}$>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:[a-zA-Z_]+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:[a-zA-Z_]+>/<id:^[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12}$>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:[a-zA-Z_]+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
```

When I browse like

```
http://localhost/mywebapp/index.php/account/2BE9515F-F388-4974-BCBB-C485C58BDF7A
```

, the result is still HTTP 404 not found.

But when I browse like

```
http://localhost/mywebapp/index.php/account/index
```

, it works fine.
So what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks agian, Michael!
I have found what the problem lays on! The regular expression can not match properly.
So I changed as follows and it works fine:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:[({]?(0x)?[0-9a-fA-F]{8}([-,]?(0x)?[0-9a-fA-F]{4}){2}((-?[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-?[0-9a-fA-F]{12})|(,\{0x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}(,0x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}){7}\}))[)}]?>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:[a-zA-Z_]+>/<id:[({]?(0x)?[0-9a-fA-F]{8}([-,]?(0x)?[0-9a-fA-F]{4}){2}((-?[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-?[0-9a-fA-F]{12})|(,\{0x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}(,0x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}){7}\}))[)}]?>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:[a-zA-Z_]+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:[a-zA-Z_]+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The first matching rule wins. In your case, it's likely that the URL rule `'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'` matches `/account/2BE9515F-F388-4974-BCBB-C485C58BDF7A` (`<controller>`=`account` and `<id>`=`2`). You should move your second rule to the top.

Rule of thumb: More specific URL rules should be listed before more general rules.

Comment: Thanks Michael! I have followed what you said and changed like this: 
'<controller:\w+>/<id:^[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12}$>'=>'<controller>/view'
'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:[a-zA-Z_]+>/<id:^[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12}$>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:[a-zA-Z_]+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:[a-zA-Z_]+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',.But  it doesn't work! How can I fix it?